# “Alloc magic is broken”/No bootable devices found on non-dual boot computer

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Bit stressed given that online classes start soon but here we go:

After turning my computer on this morning, as I have done every day for the past 2 years, I was given this message:

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic has invalid signature.
alloc magic is broken at 0x2ba183c0: 2b95be20
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

My computer is a Dell XPS 9370, and it came direct from Dell with Ubuntu already installed (no dual-booting, which I see is the basis for most other similar problems). I haven’t done anything to modify my computer that would have led to this error. I simply shut it down last night and turned it back on this morning.

Dell SupportAssist initially told me that there were no hardware problems and that something might be wrong with the BIOS, but running it now simply returns `No bootable devices found.`

Most fixes for this either involve a Live CD (which I don’t have) or installing boot repair. I have access to the GRUB2 boot loader, but cannot boot into recovery mode.

Should I try installing boot repair? I don’t have a USB with me but I could get one from a friend. Or do I have to fix it in some other way?

### Additional info:

- System BIOS: 1.3.3
- ePSA: Build 4306.11 UEFI ROM
- UEFI boot sequence is set to ubuntu. Secure boot is enabled.

The system has not been changed from the factory defaults. No dual-boots, partitions, nothing.

Any tips would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I run into the same problem last week. I tried few things but they didn't work. If you don't need the data on your pc, you can simply re-install Ubuntu (or whatever flavor you use). If the data is important then you must try to fix the problem. If you re-install, make sure you use a cd and not a usb stick.
I found this link very useful. You need to follow step by step. You can still boot your pc with a usb stick with the latest version of Ubuntu but instead of installing the OS, you click on try Ubuntu. Once you get to the desktop, you follow the instructions . (see my next comment).

Comment: (continue). You want to use the advanced section of boot repair not "the recommended one". In the advanced section, you put a check mark on rebuild Grub and on just about every other option. Here's the link and good luck.
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/

Comment: I would like to recover my files but I guess it wouldn’t be the end of the world if I completely reinstalled. In any case, looks like I’ll need to get my hands on a CD/USB and try boot repair. Thanks for the link!

Comment: you can also follow the instructions on this video. They may help and allow you to avoid a re-install and the use of boot-repair.
error: No Bootable device found Fix | Dell
.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41yjrL88rfo

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot fixed the problem. Time to back up my files! Thank you!!

Comment: Good news! Backup, and then do the remainder of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Secure Boot**

Secure Boot should be disabled in your BIOS.

**Corrupt Ubuntu**

If Secure Boot doesn't fix your problem, then you may have some file corruption. Try booting to an older kernel from the GRUB menu, and see if it boots.

Note: Edit your question with screenshots of the `Disks` app SMART Data scrollable window.

Note: If the remainder of my answer doesn't fix the problem, you **may** just have to reinstall Ubuntu.

**fsck**

Let's check for a file system problem...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**BIOS**

Dell XPS 9370

You have BIOS version 1.3.3.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.13.1, dated 8/19/2020, and it can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-13-9370-laptop/drivers).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.